# How can we apply Slicing (Python) in real-life cases. Can someone provide me some industrial examples?

Tags: python, data-analysis

Im about to learn about Python in order to work with data analysis - and would like to know how do we apply slicing in real life cases. If someone has some examples from the real life

Comment: Are you just referring to `[:]` slicing?

Answer (score 0):

slicing is used to separate/get a specified part of something right?

so lets say i have some purchase data from my website

this data includes satisfaction level, average income, amount spent and time spent looking to purchase an item.

if i wanted to see if there was any correlation between income and amount spent on my website i could use slicing to only retrieve data from incomes that are above a certain point.

all in all slicing is used to manipulate data, and its crucial for data preparation in data analysis.